# Vue js compare 2 object and remove differences in watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My data:

```
data() {
  return {
    currentStore: this.store,
    brands: [],
  }
},
```

My v-select

```
<v-select
    v-model="currentStore.brands.data"
    :options="allBrands"
    :taggable="true"
    :multiple="true"
/>
```

I have a watcher on an object that looks like this (this.newVal):

```
brands:Object
 data:Array[1]
  0:Object
    name:"3T"
 data:Array[1]
  0:Object
    name:"abc"
```

I want to compare that object with this one (this.allBrands)

```
allBrands:Array[254]
  0:Object
    name:"3T"
  1:Object
    name:"Achielle"
```

As you can see I want the name "abc" is not in the second object to I want to remove it from the watcher, this is what I have:

```
Object.keys(newVal).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
});


watch: {
  "store.brands.data": function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(this.allBrands);
    console.log(newVal);

    Object.keys(newVal).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
    });
  }
},
```

I get the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'allBrands' of undefined"

My goal is to have in my `store.brands.data` only:

```
brands:Object
 data:Array[1]
  0:Object
    name:"3T"
```

since thats the only one thats in `this.allBrands`

#### EDIT

```
Object.keys(newVal).forEach((key) => {
    if (!Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name)) {
        newVal.pop();
    }
});
```

This gives me the following error that I don't understand:

> Error in callback for watcher "store.brands.data": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: For your v-select, I am seeing `v-model="currentStore.brands.data"` but you are watching for `store.brands.data`. Which is it? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Tony I edited OP, it's the same

Answer (score 1):

As per the error you mentioned looks like `this` is getting undefined which you method is not able to find the `vue instance`

The problem is with the binding of `this` to your `function`. You need to use `arrow fn` to lexically bind `this`.

```
watch: {
  "store.brands.data": function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(this.allBrands);
    console.log(newVal);
```

To either update or delete the property from an vue object i recommend you to use `delete` ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

```
    Object.keys(newVal).forEach((key) => {
      console.log(Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: I see I forgot about the binding! Thanks! Do you maybe know how I can remove the invalid entry in my object when the `.includes()` is false?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand that Vue-delete, doesn't seem to be what I need

Comment: Can you see my edited OP, I don't understand why I can't just remove the last item form my newVal to set the value

Answer (score 0):

Like, @Satyam Pathak wrote, the reason for the first error was a binding issue which can be solved many ways, but the most modern solution is to use the arrow function.

```js
// Use of an arrow function

watch: {
  "store.brands.data": (newVal, oldVal) => { // use arrow functions in both places for consistency. 
    console.log(this.allBrands);
    console.log(newVal);

    Object.keys(newVal).forEach((key) => { // use an arrow function to bind the context to the parent context
      console.log(Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
    });
  }
},


// Use of a constant to capture the context of the parent

watch: {
  "store.brands.data": function (newVal, oldVal) {
    const self = this;

    Object.keys(newVal).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(Object.values(self.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
    });
  }
},

// Bind the function to return a function that is bound to the parent context
watch: {
  "store.brands.data": function (newVal, oldVal) {
    Object.keys(newVal).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(Object.values(this.allBrands).includes(newVal[key].name));
    }.bind(this));
  }
},
```

With regard to the second issue, if `newVal` is in this form below

```js
brands:Object
 data:Array[1]
  0:Object
    name:"3T"
 data:Array[1]
  0:Object
    name:"abc"
```

the reason you are getting the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"` is because

`Object.keys(newVal) returns "data"` and newValue.data returns an array with the object a.

Therefore `newVal.data.name` will return an error. An option will be to loop through each array, but that's not an ideal approach.

I have thought of many ways to solve this problem but they involve multiple for-loops which would be inefficient and frankly not worth even sharing. It's a horrible coding practice.

You should consider simplifying the data structure of `newVal`.For instance, `newVal` is an object of arrays. Can it be simplified to an array of objects?