# How to detect changes in property values in object in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On top of [How to watch only after the initial load from API in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879717/how-to-watch-only-after-the-initial-load-from-api-in-vuejs/69880156?noredirect=1#comment123531591_69880156), I wanted to detect any changes in values of the properties in the json object.

Initially the user object is

```
user: {
        userId: 0,
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        completed: false,
      },
```

I have two input fields,

```
 <input type="text" v-model="user.userId" /> <br />
 <input type="text" v-model="user.title" /> <br />
```

and a button `<button :disabled="isLoaded">Update</button>`

If none of the input values changed, the button should be still disabled. Example, if the userId is changed to 1, the button should be enabled but if the value is changed back to 0, the button should be disabled. I referred [Vue js compare 2 object and remove differences in watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298782/vue-js-compare-2-object-and-remove-differences-in-watcher) and I tried following but failed.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="!isFetching">
      <input type="text" v-model="user.userId" /> <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" v-model="user.title" /> <br />
      <br />
      <button :disabled="isLoaded">Update</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        userId: 0,
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        completed: false,
      },
      isFetching: false,
      isLoaded: true,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    user: {
      handler(oldVal, newVal) {
        this.checkObject(oldVal, newVal);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkObject: (obj1, obj2) => {
      const isEqual = (...objects) =>
        objects.every(
          (obj) => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(objects[0])
        );
      console.log(obj1, obj2);
      console.log(isEqual(obj1, obj2));
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.isFetching = true;
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.user = json;
        this.isLoaded = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.isFetching = false));
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-hopper-ynhxc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You could create a computed value with the given logic to evaluate whether disabled shall be true or false. `computed: { disabled() { return //elaborated function which checks all necessary information }}` and then bind it on the item `:disabled="disabled"`

Comment: FWIW, the problem with the answer you picked is that it adds complexity but doesn't solve problems with a watcher. You still use isLoaded property that serves no good purpose.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you suggest a way? I am too confused

Comment: Loading state can be handled like I showed in previous answer, there's no need for a watcher for it. You preferably shouldn't enable a form before data is loaded, if a user starts to fill the form and then it's changed when initial data arrives, this results in bad UX. As for form changes, it's like current answer shows. You need to copy `user` and compare against it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could solve this. So below I'm storing two user objects, one is my base line comparison `compareUser`, and the other is the `user` that is under edit. When something changes which the deep watch on `user` will notify me about, I use a utility function like `isEqual` from lodash to perform a semantic comparison of the base line object and the current user object, and see if there are any differences.

If I want to update my base line that I'm comparing to, then I update the `compareUser` from the current `user` by cloning it.

You can of course replace things like `isEqual` and `cloneDeep` by rolling your own to avoid the extra library if that's an issue.

```
<script>
import { isEqual, cloneDeep } from "lodash";

const createDefault = function () {
  return {
    userId: 0,
    id: 0,
    title: "",
    completed: false,
  };
};

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      compareUser: createDefault(),
      user: createDefault(),
      isLoaded: false,
      isDifferent: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    user: {
      handler() {
        this.isDifferent = !isEqual(this.user, this.compareUser);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setCompareUser(user) {
      this.compareUser = cloneDeep(user);
      this.isDifferent = false;
    },
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );
    const user = await response.json();
    this.user = user;
    this.setCompareUser(user);
    this.isLoaded = true;
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-tdd-yg6c1

Comment: Thank you so much for trying. Is there any way to achieve this without installing a 3rd party package?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the demo to replace the lodash functions with extremely rudimentary alternatives.

Comment: Thank you so much man Steve <3. Is it good that we follow this basic alternatives?

Comment: It's probably fine for most cases.  The `isEqual` could be more efficient if done properly, it's not easy to recurse an object graph looking for changes. `cloneDeep` most likely outperforms serializing and deserializing the JSON by quite a bit. However, we're talking probably small amounts here so unless the volumes are large or performance requirements very high, and your object remains relatively simple, it's not likely to be a problem.

Comment: Hi. When I am trying with another array of objects inside the given object, its not checking properly. I tried creating another data property to hold the info but I am failing. Can you please help me out here? (with nested array of objects inside the given object)